# pass mocked s3 connection to other methods

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I wanted to mock the s3 connection once inside a particular method and pass it to other methods instead of using @mock_s3 on top of all methods and reduce repeated code.
Any pointers on this would be helpful

```
class App_Test(unittest.TestCase):
@mock_s3
def get_s3_bucket(self):
    return boto3.resource('s3').create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)

def some_test(self):
    s3_bucket = get_s3_bucket()
    ....

def some_test_123(self):
    s3_bucket = get_s3_bucket()
    ....
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html) is an option, this something I like to do with AWS mocks when using moto:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_s3_bucket():
    with mock_s3():
        yield boto3.resource('s3').create_bucket(Bucket="test_bucket")

def test_1(mock_s3_bucket):
    ...
```

It creates a fresh bucket for each test and `with` ensures cleanup is done properly after each test.

Comment: This isn't working . its looking for aws credentials .Should i move the methods out of class ?

Comment: @sai are you using pytest or unittest to run your tests?

Comment: unittest @Tzane

Comment: Pytest fixtures don't work with unittest, but unittest test classes work with pytest.

Comment: could you please working code. Without unit test also its not working

Comment: The example works on my machine.